# Email System in PHP using PHPMailer

Tags: php

Hi i am currently implementing an email system for a customer in php. I'm having a bit of trouble in figuring out something. Here's a sample code:

```
   $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
   $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
   $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
   $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
   $mail->Port = 465;
   $mail->Username = "***missing part***";
   $mail->Password = "***missing part***";
   $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
   $mail->Subject = $subject;
   $mail->Body = $body;
   $mail->AddAddress($to);
```

My customer already created a business email account on gmail for this website. My question is should i put this business email and password in these missing parts? Anyone could help me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> whose username and password should i put there?

If you want to use GMail, you need to put in the username and password that belong to the GMail account you want to send the message from.

.... which is why sending E-Mail through GMail is a bit of an imperfect solution IMO - you put your personal Google login data, with which you can access everything you do on Google, into a script on a server. It's not great practice security-wise.

It might be more feasible to create a SMTP account on the client's web site, and use that. That has the additional advantage that you can use a `email@clients-domain-name.com` sender address.

Comment: What do you mean to say 'on the client's website'? How do i do that?

Comment: You could create an account on Gmail specifically for this, so at least it's not your *personal* email account.

Comment: @Moshin if your customer has a web site running with a shared web host, they usually have the possibility to send E-Mail through that. You'd have to ask their web host for their SMTP login data. Maybe you should add some more information about your situation and what you want to do

Comment: @Peka - I wonder how many comments I miss because people put two `r`'s in my first name? `:P` (It happens *all* the time.)

Comment: @Jared It's the `rr` of your last name that engrains itself into the mind of the careless reader. Sorry. :)

Comment: @Pekka - No worries; it's actually happened several times over the couple days for some reason. I do wonder though...

Answer (score 0):

you must post the username and password so we can help you.. LOL, just kidding. You should put there the username and password of the account that would be sending the email. In this case, probably your webpage's gmail account.

Comment: Nice one lol. Actually the website is for a customer. Should i put his username and password?

Comment: yes and no. It should be an account from him, but not his primary account. Create an account just for the webpage and use that one.

Answer (score 0):

Often web hosts don't use authentication for their web servers to send email using their smtp servers, i would suggest contacting the people who host the website and ask them about using their smtp servers.

Using gmail (if you can from a script) might end up with the rather annoying reply thing that you get from gmail where the reply address is a gmail account.

e.g. from mrKoz@gmail.com on behalf of mr@koz.com which doesn't look awesome :)